# Xcode 12.1 simulator push notifications not working

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios14

I am trying to use Firebase push notifications in Ionic/Angular capacitor app.
I am following [this tutorial](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase).
When I was using Xcode 11.3 OS Mojave the simulator gave the error:

> remote notifications are not supported in the simulator

I searched around and discovered that push notifications on simulators were only supported with Xcode 11.4+ and OS Catalina and above. So I updated to Catalina and Xcode 12.1 but I am still getting the same error.

Any input appreciated.